# What is ms.pgarea in html?

Tags: html, web

As an upcoming web developer, I wanted to emulate some websites. I usually just look at the page and speculate what tags they use, but this time I wanted to do it another way to see what I didn't know. It always takes a really long time for me to remake websites, so I looked at the source of https://careers.microsoft.com/students/explore.

And I saw this line:

```
 <header class="navbar" ms.pgarea="Header">
```

I cant seem to find what the ms.pgarea part means. Can someone explain what this means?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure which one but this looks like they are using some kind of framework for their website, probably a self-made one (that's the reason for the `ms.`-prefix). This attribute contains probably data used by that framework.

Comment: If it was a framework, is there some way I can tell looking at the header or something?

Comment: I have quickly scanned through the source code and I haven't found any indication. So their framework might either be backend or I just missed something. Both are likely.